# How to add users to a roster in xmpp?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I have successfully created a user using the following code:

```
accountmanager = new org.jivesoftware.smack.AccountManager(connection);
accountmanager.createAccount(fbuserid,fbuserid);
```

But I am not able to add other users to the logged in user's roster using the following code :

```
 public void createEntry(String user, String name, String[] groups) throws XMPPException {
    // Create and send roster entry creation packet.
    RosterPacket rosterPacket = new RosterPacket();
    rosterPacket.setType(IQ.Type.SET);
    RosterPacket.Item item = new RosterPacket.Item(user, name);
    if (groups != null) {
        for (String group : groups) {
            if (group != null) {
                item.addGroupName(group);
            }
        }
    }
    rosterPacket.addRosterItem(item);
    // Wait up to a certain number of seconds for a reply from the server.
    PacketCollector collector = connection.createPacketCollector(
            new PacketIDFilter(rosterPacket.getPacketID()));
    connection.sendPacket(rosterPacket);
    IQ response = (IQ) collector.nextResult(SmackConfiguration.getPacketReplyTimeout());
    collector.cancel();
    if (response == null) {
        throw new XMPPException("No response from the server.");
    }
    // If the server replied with an error, throw an exception.
    else if (response.getType() == IQ.Type.ERROR) {
        throw new XMPPException(response.getError());
    }

    // Create a presence subscription packet and send.
    Presence presencePacket = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
    presencePacket.setTo(user);
    connection.sendPacket(presencePacket);
}
```

I am always getting the response as null. Someone please help me to solve this and Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it your code, or it is body of Smack's `Roster` class? Are you getting `XMPPError` or `XMPPException` - so simply "no response from server"?

Comment: Its a body of Smack's Roster class and I am getting the  XMPP Exception.

Comment: Are u testing against your own serwer? - Check the logs. If 3rd party, please contact sysadmin as either there is some sort of error on server side (but not unchecked one), roster creation is forbidden or server implementation is not XEP compliant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rosters and presence use a permissions-based model where users must give permission before they are added to someone else's roster. This protects a user's privacy by making sure that only approved users are able to view their presence information. Therefore, when you add a new roster entry it will be in a pending state until the other user accepts your request.

If another user requests a presence subscription so they can add you to their roster, you must accept or reject that request. Smack handles presence subscription requests in one of three ways:

Automatically accept all presence subscription requests.
Automatically reject all presence subscription requests.
Process presence subscription requests manually. The mode can be set using the
Roster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode) method. Simple clients normally use one of the automated subscription modes, while full-featured clients should manually process subscription requests and let the end-user accept or reject each request. If using the manual mode, a PacketListener should be registered that listens for Presence packets that have a type of Presence.Type.subscribe.

Try this in code first to add user in roster as well as requesting the users permission.

```
    roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection);
            if (!roster.isLoaded())
                try {
                    roster.reloadAndWait();
                } catch (SmackException.NotLoggedInException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "NotLoggedInException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "NotConnectedException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
   roster.createEntry(jID, name, null);
```

On other user side/ in your code after login from one user:

```
    roster.setSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
```

To make user status online:

```
    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
            presence.setStatus("Online, Programmatically!");
            presence.setPriority(24);
            presence.setMode(Presence.Mode.available);
            roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection);
```

Comment: I am getting null pointer exception while calling the createEntry()

Comment: There might possibility that roster is not properly initialised. In my case i have initialized like above, check for the edited answer.